# Make a draggable element responsive to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a resizable and draggable div , but am not able to make it responsive to the window , i gave left 20% but if I change the windows size the position is not changing according to the window even if I gave the attributes in percentage of the window ,I want the draggable element's position and size according to the window percentage , Can any one help in this issue

```js
$('div').resizable();
$('div').draggable({
  appendTo: 'body',
  start: function(event, ui) {
    isDraggingMedia = true;
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    isDraggingMedia = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="border:1px solid #00FF7F;position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:20%;left:20%;  width:26%; height:26% ; overflow:hidden;">
    <img style="  width:100%; height:100%" src="http://www.clipartkid.com/images/68/baby-toys-jpg-19-feb-2010-10-37-50k-FSIRmi-clipart.jpg" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Above code is working the way it supposed to be work, what do you exactly want?

Comment: Which browser is giving you problems?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I guess he wants the position of the "resizable and draggable div" to be relative to window.

Comment: I want the position and size of the div to be relative to the window as a responsive page.

Comment: i want the div 's  size and alignment  according to the size of the window,

Comment: @BhanuTharun you want the `div` the be adjusted when the `window` size is changed, is that correct? What have you tried so far? Do you want both height and width to retain their current aspect ratio and how small do you want it to scale? What do you want to have happen when the window gets larger? or too small to show the content?

Answer (score 1):

Without having a clear idea at what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to know if this will help you.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ch3fhs3o/

**HTML**

```
<div class="diag">
  <img src="https://www.clipartkid.com/images/68/baby-toys-jpg-19-feb-2010-10-37-50k-FSIRmi-clipart.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.diag {
  border: 1px solid #00FF7F;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.diag img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var isDraggingMedia;
  $(".diag").css({
    width: Math.round($(window).width() * 0.26) + "px",
    height: Math.round($(window).height() * 0.26) + "px",
    top: Math.round($(window).height() * 0.20) + "px",
    left: Math.round($(window).width() * 0.20) + "px"
  });
  $(".diag").resizable();
  $(".diag").draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    start: function(event, ui) {
      isDraggingMedia = true;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      isDraggingMedia = false;
    }
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    console.log("Window Width:", $(window).width(), "Height:", $(window).height());
    var dW = Math.round($(window).width() * 0.26);
    var dH = Math.round($(window).height() * 0.26);
    var dL = Math.round($(window).width() * 0.20);
    var dT = Math.round($(window).height() * 0.20);
    console.log("Dialog Width:", dW, "Height:", dH);
    $(".diag").css({
      width: dW + "px",
      height: dH + "px",
      top: dT + "px",
      left: dL + "px"
    }).trigger("resize");
  })
});
```

I preferred to set a class name to make the selecting easier. You can see that when the `window` is resized, it also resizes and resets the `top, left` the draggable.

There are some caveats in this, but I am not sure if that's what you're looking for again.